# How to cast/fling videos from Kindle Fire to Kindle Fire TV

Tags: android, kindle-fire, amazon-fire-tv

I'm developing a video player on both Kindle Fire and Fire TV. According to [this article](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/dial-integration), I can integrate `DIAL` to integrate the `second screen` feature. After doing the `DIAL integrate`, I still can't implement this feature. What else should be done?

The best case is that, if under the same wifi environment, the tablet can detect there's a TV device and then show an icon, user clicks the icon, the Fire TV can play the video, kinda like `chromeCast` and normal Android devices(with play services)

How to do that on Kindle Fire devices?

Comment: DIAL is used to launch the app, and pass a payload (URI) which tells the launched app what to do

Answer (score 1):

A year too late maybe, but Amazon recently released "Amazon Fling SDK" that addresses the second screen use case you are interested in.

This SDK provides libraries for Amazon, Android, and iOS apps. The library handles discovery of the Fire TVs on the same WiFi network. Once it is discovered, you can communicate with a Fire TV through a proxy object. The RPC mechanics are hidden behind this proxy object.

You can fling videos, audio, and photos to the Amazon Fire TV from Kindles, Android devices, and iOS devices.

You can also listen for status changes on the Fire TV by providing callbacks.

Reference: https://developer.amazon.com/fling